# How to extract an image path and its date and time exif data from a filesystem into a database - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, image-processing, exif

I want to use Ruby on Rails to make a simple web page that looks up the time an image was taken from exif data and looks up the current time and displays an image if both times match.

I'm going to put hundreds, maybe a few thousand images into a ruby on rails folder. I'll do this only once however and it will never change or be added to.

What's the best way to get the path of these images and also the corresponding exif data into an sql database? i dont really need an uploader if im dragging the images into the folder or am i wrong?

Would i be best served by using an external storage like amazon s3 and using active storage and something like exifr to extract the exif time data to the database and serve the image that way? as here:
https://www.georg-ledermann.de/blog/2018/05/15/exif-analyzer-for-active-storage/

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks. im really trying to get my head around this before attempting a start.

Answer (score 1):

> I used `exif` gem a while ago, I think it's exactly what you're
>   looking

```
gem install exif
brew install libexif
```

> load data from the file

```
data = Exif::Data.new(File.open('sample.jpg'))
data.date_time # output => "2019:01:08 21:14:11"
```

Take a look at the gem [documentation](https://github.com/tonytonyjan/exif) for more options

Comment: thanks for your reply. im going to try and make a start on this today.

Comment: let me know if it was helpful.